# Can't sort an array of object after pushing a new item into it

Tags: arrays, sorting, react-native

I have an issue sorting an array under react-native.

So I have this array of object which I fetch from an url.
each object looks like this :
`{id: "66", activityHash: "2814646673", hashOrigin: "activity", mapIcon: "th_cat.png", mapImage: "", …}`

Once I get that array I do :
`data.Response.map`

In this array.map I launch a SQLite query on each 'activityHash' which returns the name which is stored in a local SQLite database.

Then I push each item into a new array:

```
item.name = parsedJson.displayProperties.name
mapDataTemp.push(item)
```

And to finish I want to sort it on the name key I just added above:
`sortedMapData = [...mapDataTemp].sort((a, b) => {return a.name - b.name})`

But I can't get anything on the screen except one entry (there is 47)

I think this is because once I want to sort my array, the array.map process has not finished to process, but can't find a proper way to correct/solve it.
I just started React-native so excuse my dumb question :p

```
      GetArcadiaData(this.url).then(data => {

        this.setState({isLoading: false})

        data.Response.map( (item, index) => {
          if (item.hashOrigin == '111') {
            item.name = I18n.t('maps_public_event')
            mapDataTemp.push(item)
          }
          else {
            sqliteReadHash(item.hashOrigin, item.activityHash)
              .then((parsedJson) => {
                //console.log(parsedJson.displayProperties.name)
                item.name = parsedJson.displayProperties.name
                mapDataTemp.push(item)
              })
            }
        })

        console.log(mapDataTemp)
        sortedMapData = [...mapDataTemp].sort((a, b) => {return a.name - b.name})
        console.log(sortedMapData)

        this.setState({
          mapData: sortedMapData
        })

      })
```

GetArcadiaData is the function which fetches the raw data

sqliteReadHash is the function that read the local database and collects the right name corresponding to the activityHash

Answer (score 0):

You can try below on your sort function

```
.sort((a,b)=> a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

you are comparing strings so I just added localCompare method to compare the strings.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for helping! unfortunatly the result is the same. the console.log(mapDataTemp) show me all unsorted data and the console.log(sortedMapData) show me only one line.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
[...mapDataTemp].sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
    if(a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! unfortunatly the result is the same. the console.log(mapDataTemp) show me all unsorted data and the console.log(sortedMapData) show me only one line